# Mouse/keyboard not working with scrcpy, how to fix?

Tags: windows, external-keyboard, mouse, scrcpy

My Samsung Galaxy A24 phone used to work fine with my Windows 10  laptop via scrcpy.exe, on a USB-C cable. I did not change anything in the setup. Suddenly,  now scrcpy shows the phone's screen fine on the laptop's screen, but mouse clicks have no effect, both left-click and right-click.  How do I fix this? What I have tried is:

- Restart the phone;
- Pull out the USB cable cable and connect again.
- Revoke USB debugging permissions;
- Turn off and then on USB debugging. To no avail.

Still, mouse clicks do nothing, whereas the phone's screen is shown fine, and directly touching the phone's own screen with the finger works as expected.

Comment: What is the full output in the console? Do you use the latest version of scrcpy? (there are regular updates to adapt to Android changes)

Comment: check Developer options for *"USB debugging (Security settings) Allow granting permissions and simulating input via USB debugging*"